# Linux to IIS ftp get script

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, iis, ftp

I am struggling with how to set up a login script from a Linux client to an IIS server. I've tried here documents and a traditional echo script piped into the ftp (client) command, and my script is still prompted for username and password. I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong.

I have set up an IIS ftp site that responds to normal command line login.

`ftp -i my-host`

(fill in unam and pwd when prompted)

From Linux ftp client to Linux ftp server I can usually do something like

```
echo -e "user anonymous\\nbin\\nmget csm.exp.tar.gz" \
 | ftp -i -n my-server > /dev/null
```

but connecting to an IIS/ftp server, this still prompts for password, but not user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use just FTP client from linux why don't you use it like

```
ftp -n -i $SERVER <<End-of-Session
    user username "password"
    binary
    bell
    pwd
    bye
    End-of-Session
```

Not all of these commands are required (e.g. binary). Resolution with echoing username and password is a bit dirty.